# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting what it seems to be a missing loader error when trying to use SASS with webpack and react.js

I have modified the code in webpack:

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack')

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  var loaders = ['react-hot','babel']
} else {
  var loaders = ['babel']
}
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './app-client.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: loaders,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    { 
     test: /\.scss$/, 
     loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"] 
    }
  ]},
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET)
    })
 ]
};
```

Inside `./components/App.js` I have the following:

```
//styles
import style from '../styles/footer.scss'
```

Inside the `./components/partials/Footer.js` I modified the `className` value to the following: `<footer className={ style.foo }>`. However now the page loads blank with the following error:

`Footer.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: style is not defined`

I then moved the import inside the Footer.js component:

`import style from '../../styles/footer.scss'`

But now I am getting:
`ReactReconciler.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNativeNode' of null`

Where do I import style?

Answer (score -1):

Take away the sass in there, your config should look like this

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader" }
```

Comment: I did that, replacing the above with your line. I still have the same error.